# What is the type of an Input field that is passed into a TypeScript function

Tags: angular, typescript

I am following an Angular 2 tutorial in which an `input` element is passed to a function via click event.

The tutorial has an addTodo function with this signature `addTodo(event, todoText){ }`. This code is throwing up warning of Parameter 'todoText' has an implicit 'any' type.

I am wondering if there is a TypeScript object that that I can use in place of `any` that represents a `form input control`

**Example Angular 2 HTML**

```
<div class="add-todo-form text-center">
  <h1>Add ToDo</h1>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Add Todo.." autofocus #todoText>
    <br>
    <button (click)="addTodo($event, todoText)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Create</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example Typescript**

```
addTodo(event: any, todoText: any){
  console.log('xxxxxxxxxxx');
  var result: any;

  var newTodo = {
    text: todoText,
    isCompleted: false
  };

  result = this._todoService.saveTodo(newTodo);

  result.subscribe( (x: any)=> {
    this.todos.push(newTodo);
    todoText.value = '';
  })
}
```

Comment: You can pass the value *directly*: `addTodo($event, todoText.value)` and in method just type it as `string`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer by @Gunter was close and helped lead me to what I wanted, I was able to drill down into `lib.es6.d.ts` to find `HTMLInputElement` which extends `HTMLElement`

Answer (score 1):

If it's a component or directive, then the instance of the component or directive is passed, otherwise `HTMLElement`